# Why do changes applied to bootstrap.css not work when published but do work on localhost?

Tags: css, asp.net, bootstrap-4, master-pages

I'm building an asp.net website (webforms) in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.2 (26430.16) and Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.7.03056. (targetFramework .NET = 4.5.2).

Upon creation of the solution a bootstrap.css file is created, together with the Site.master and so on.

When I edit the bootstrap.css file I can see changes happening when viewing the website on localhost. But after publishing to my host, it doesn't seem to have applied those changes to the live website.

Part of my 'Site.master' page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title>CompanyX | <%: Page.Title %></title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="CompanyX, ..." class="next-head" />
    <meta name="author" content="CompanyX" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <meta property="og:title" content="CompanyX" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="..." />

    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Stylesheets" runat="server">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Site.css" type="text/css" runat = "server" />
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <%-- navbar css styling is done in the 'bootstrap.css' file --%>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">
                        <asp:Image ID="logo" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/logo.png" AlternateText="logo" style="width:15%; height:auto;"></asp:Image>
                        <span>CompanyX</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" runat="server" href="#">Products<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Product-1">Product-1</a></li>
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Product-2">Product-2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Photos">Photos</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container body-content">
            ...
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
```

A change I applied in the 'bootstrap.css' file:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: medium;
}
```

I added a `margin-top: 10px;` here, so my items from the `navbar-collapse collapse` are horizontally aligned with the logo and text from `navbar-brand`.

I'd expect this to work for both, localhost and published website.

I also tried adding the below code to `asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Stylesheets"` as an extra reference to the `bootstrap.css` file, but no luck there either.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" runat="server" href="/Content/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
```

Your input is much appreciated.

Below you can see the result visualized:
[image: localhost]

[image: published]

### Update:

Actually it looks like something strange is going on, when viewing the page source code.

My code to render CSS on my Site.master:
[image: css code]

On localhost, the source code looks like this:
[image: css localhost]

On published website, the source code looks like this:
[image: css website]

And I just realized I don't need the `ContentPlaceHolder ID="Stylesheets"`. I've now removed it from my code, but the problem remains.

Any thoughts on why this is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution for me was to remove the css bundling.

I removed this line of code:
`<webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />`
and also removed the *Bundle.config* file.

In my `<head>` tag I now have the below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" runat="server" href="/Content/Site.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" runat="server" href="/Content/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I do like to add that this solution may / will probably not be the best. If a better solution is available, feel free to add.

Answer (score 3):

There could be multiple reasons behind that, my guess would be these:

1. It could be, your browser have cached the CSS file and is
   using the file from there. Try clearing the browser cache or use
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> if using Firefox or Chrome to hard-reload the
   page.
2. Or it could be because your visual studio is not uploading the CSS
   file. Try manually replacing the file via FileZilla.
3. There could be a style mentioned in the head or after your specified changes, that are over writing your changes. Inspect if there are no changes in style after the desired changes are being applied.
4. Check, if there are some style attributes mentioned with an `!important` flag. If there are, this would mean it is taking precedence over your normal styles even you specify them after the desired changes.

Comment: Visual Studio first deletes all files from Plesk (GoDaddy hosting) and then uploads everything, I verified and the bootstrap.css file is uploaded.
I verified in Edge and Chrome, in-private and normal, I also tried ctrl+shift+r but no success.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Isn't the ScriptManager referencing the bootstrap file?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the CSS files are not being published properly on the server.
Solution:

1. You can manually replace CSS on the server or make changes in the publish release configuration setting by selecting the "delete all existing files prior to publish" option. this solution worked for me (as shown in the image below)
2. if any required CSS file was excluded in the past in the Visual Studio Project, include those files and re-publish your project.

[image]